# Querying data in 0-30 minute groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, datediff, dateadd

I have a script that runs every 30 minutes that runs a query looking for new records within the previous 30 minutes. To account for any type of delay of the script running, I'd like to look in the pervious 0:00-30:00 minute, and 30:01-59:59 chunks.

For example, if my script runs at 11:00am, I'd expect it to find new rows that have an

`entered_date > 10:30 am AND < 11:00 am`

And when it ran at 11:30am, I'd expect new rows from an `entered_date > 11:00am AND < 11:30am.

Doing something like this only gets the last running 30 minutes:

```
SELECT
    fa.entered_date,
    fa.text
FROM
    form_answers fa 
WHERE
    AND fa.value = 1
    AND fa.entered_date >= DATEADD(mi, -30, GETDATE())
```

So if my script was somehow delayed by a few seconds, and ran at 11:00:02, I could potentially miss a record that has an `entered_date` of 10:30:01.

EDIT:

This is what ended up working for me:

```
    fa.entered_date BETWEEN 
        DATEADD(mi,-30,CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, GETDATE())/30*30, 0))) 
    AND 
        DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, GETDATE())/30*30, 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no sure-fire way to process "new" records based on time alone - even if you track the "last" processed time, there could be records that get missed, or records that get processed twice.

Some alternate methods:

- Track the last `entered_date` that was processed and process anything that is added after that time.
- Track the last ID that is processed, and process any records with a higher ID (assuming your table uses an incrementing key).
- Add a flag or status field to your records to know if they've been processed or not
- Use a queue that is filled when records are added (using a trigger) and processed periodically.

If you *DO* have to rely on the clock alone, then I would round the "current" time to the nearest 30-minute interval and lock back 30 minutes from *there*.  So if the current time is `11:00:02`, it would round it to `11:00:00` and process records that were added between `10:30:00` and `11:00:00`.

Comment: I agree with your, and Gordon's suggestions about different methods of tracking. However, I cannot insert data into this particular database, only query the data. It really only leaves me with using the clock method. Could you provide an example of rounding the "current" time to the nearest, and then look back 30 minutes from the rounded time?

Comment: With your suggestion, I think something like this could work: http://pastebin.com/SBeZTwKw

Answer (score 3):

Depending on clock time in scripts is a bad idea. Your script may not run for some other reason -- SQL Server agent is not running, for instance, or the server is re-booted at just the time when it would run, or a new person accidentally unchecks a box. Or, it may run twice in some period.

If you want robustness, then keep a log table of the last time the script was run.  Then read from the log, something like:

```
select @lastlogtime = max(lastreadtime)
from log;
```

And use this in your query instead of relying on the clock.

Comment: I 100% agree that using clock time is a horrible idea. I'd much rather keep track of when a script ran, however, I am unable to insert data into this particular database. Just query.

Comment: @etm124 . . . Perhaps you should get your own database for such tables, in that case (it can be a different database).  It seems an odd structure where you can have a job running but have not write privileges anywhere on the server.  As a last resort, you can keep such information in a file, but that is perverse when you are running a database job.